# How to get kubectl apply full progress until container running or error?

Tags: kubernetes

I am currently building a CI/CD pipeline where I am trying to test a simple nginx deployment, the problem is when I run `kubectl apply -f ./nginx-demplyment.yaml` I only get the output that resources got created/updated.

In my use case I the first thing i get is:

```sh
deployment.apps/nginx1.14.2 created
service/my-service created
```

And this is the output of `kubectl get all` where pods `STATUS` says **ContainerCreating**:

[image: kubectl get all output]

The problem is in my pipeline I want to run `curl` command to check if my nginx server is working properly once the image gets pulled and the pod STATUS is Running, but obviously if the image didn't get pulled yet curl will say connection refused because the container is not up yet.

How can I do that and is there a way to get the output of pulling images at least?

> the task runs the commands with && so the curl gets executed right after kubectl.

> Am working on a kind cluster with 3 control-plane nodes and 2 worker nodes.

Comment: Programatically, you can use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) to ask questions like this; it will easier and more reliable than trying to scrape `kubectl`.  Using `curl` to probe if the container is available is a fine platform-neutral approach too.  I would not recommend converting `kubectl` output to a PNG as you've done in the question, it is much harder to read and parse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kubectl wait` to wait for the deployment to be in a certain condition. Another option (or possibly used in combination) is to retry curl until the request returns a 200. An example of kubectl wait for your nginx deployment to become ready:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=available deployment/nginx
```

Comment: That's actually helpful if I was running a corn job to check for availability it worked properly, also the curl test is clever and solves my problem but since I am using a kind cluster I find that there is a way to download images before deploying to a cluster. Thanks fella!

Comment: `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app=nginx1.14.2 --timeout=60s` this might help if someone working on checking pods by app name

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a possible way to do that which is by downloading the images first then deploying Nginx.

- For **minikube** users you can run:

```sh
minikube image load <image-name>
```

- For **Kind** users which is my case:

```sh
kind load docker-image nginx:1.14.2 --name k8s-cluster
```

once the image gets pulled next command `curl` will work as wanted.